# Code splitting/react-loadable issue

Tags: reactjs, code-splitting, react-loadable

I'm trying to introduce code splitting into my app using react-loadable.  I tried it on a very simple component:

```
const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('components/Shared/Logo/Logo'),
    loading: <div>loading</div>,
});
```

However, when this component is rendered, I get the following error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `LoadableComponent`.
    in LoadableComponent (created by AppHeader)
    in div (created by AppHeader)
    in AppHeader (created by PlainChatApp)
    in div (created by PlainChatApp)
    in PlainChatApp (created by DragDropContext(PlainChatApp))
    in DragDropContext(PlainChatApp) (created by Connect(DragDropContext(PlainChatApp)))
    in Connect(DragDropContext(PlainChatApp))
    in Provider
    in AppContainer
    in ErrorBoundary

The above error occurred in the <LoadableComponent> component:
    in LoadableComponent (created by AppHeader)
    in div (created by AppHeader)
    in AppHeader (created by PlainChatApp)
    in div (created by PlainChatApp)
    in PlainChatApp (created by DragDropContext(PlainChatApp))
    in DragDropContext(PlainChatApp) (created by Connect(DragDropContext(PlainChatApp)))
    in Connect(DragDropContext(PlainChatApp))
    in Provider
    in AppContainer
    in ErrorBoundary
```

I don't see anything obvious that I'm doing wrong, and I'm unable to file an issue in that repo.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Turns out that you need to pass a component to the `loading` option and not JSX.  The documentation clearly says this, I just missed it.

Comment: I implemented code splitting (react-loadable) with the help of this tutorial https://youtu.be/AR5GSZuox1k

Comment: For more detail: loading: () => <div>loading</div>

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to use `default exports` since when you import it's not using named exports: `loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ './Home')`

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass jsx to loading key to Loadable component, provide valid react component.

```
const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('components/Shared/Logo/Logo'),
    loading: () => <div>loading</div>, // pass component, not jsx
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the guys who got here because they're server side rendering app (server babel transpiled files) spitting out the error above, it may happen because you are using airbnb babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node without setting `noInterop` to false on `.babelrc` as below:

`{
  "plugins": [
    ["dynamic-import-node", { "noInterop": true }]
  ]
}`

---